# leap year between 2 variables

Tags: r

A year is a leap year, if it can be divided by 4 but not by 100, except when it is divisible by 400. Create function ans(year1, year2), which returns all the leap years between year1 and year2. For example ans(2000,2010) should return vector c(2000,2004,2008).

I cant quite figure out what I need to do besides the code I made. Anyone up for help?

```
ans <- function(year1,year2){
for(year in year1:year2){
if((year %% 4 == 0) & (year %% 100 != 0) | (year  %% 400 == 0)){
return(year)}}}
```

Comment: You `return` from a `for` loop, which means the loop is interrupted. Perhaps you could create a `logical` vector `ind <- (year %% 4 == 0) & ...`, and then `(year1:year2)[ind]`? (No `for` loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction.

```
ans <- function(year1,year2){
vector<-c()
for(year in year1:year2){
if((year %% 4 == 0) & (year %% 100 != 0) | (year  %% 400 == 0)){
vector<-c(vector,year)
}}
return(vector)}
```

Just define a variable to store the years. Also, `return` must be before the last `}` because you are defining a function.

Answer (score 0):

R is a vectorized language, by taking advantage of that fact, one can avoid using a loop and dramatically improve performance.  The `ifelse` function takes a vector as input and returns a vector for its output.

```
ans <- function(year1,year2){
  #make a vector of all years
  year<-year1:year2
  #find the leap years (TRUE/FALSE)
  leaps<-ifelse((year %% 4 == 0) & (year %% 100 != 0) | (year  %% 400 == 0), TRUE, FALSE)
  year[leaps] #return the leap years
}

ans(2000,2010)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `leap_year` function in the lubridate package that returns TRUE for leap years, FALSE otherwise

```
ans <- function(year1, year2){
  year_seq <- year1:year2
  year_seq[lubridate::leap_year(year_seq)]
}

ans(2000,2010)
#[1] 2000 2004 2008
```